# Django - How can add multiple forms according to input enter number

Tags: python, django

I have an input field where the will customer add a number for buy membership then will get forms according to numbers 1,2, or 5 then will show 1,2, or 5 forms with input fields in which will add data.

For example:

1. customer will come to the site and click on buy membership
2. the first page will How many Memberships do you want to buy? ==> input Field in which will add 1,2, or 5
3. based on how many members enter a show a page to collect information of members

I have reached the multiple forms adding by the user with the button. But my desire is that on the first-page user will enter the number of forms which he wants then according to his number I will create the number of forms for him.

On that which I have worked with Django formsets you can see my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MemberShip(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
            ('Male', 'Male'),
            ('Female', 'Female'),
            )
    EXPERIENCE = (
            ('First Time', 'First Time'),
            ('Have skier and snowboard before', 'Have skier and snowboard before'),
            )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=EXPERIENCE)
    date_birth = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=GENDER)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
      return self.first_name
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from .models import MemberShip


MemberShipFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    MemberShip, fields=("first_name", "last_name", "experience", "date_birth", "gender", "phone"), extra=1
)
```

View.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from .forms import MemberShipFormSet
from .models import MemberShip
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class MemberShipList(ListView):
    model = MemberShip
    template_name = "customer/memberships_list.html"

class MemberShipAdd(TemplateView):
    template_name = "customer/memberships_add.html"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = MemberShipFormSet(queryset=MemberShip.objects.none())
        return self.render_to_response({'membership_formset': formset})

    # Define method to handle POST request
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):

        formset = MemberShipFormSet(data=self.request.POST)

        # Check if submitted forms are valid
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect(reverse_lazy("member_ships_list"))

        return self.render_to_response({'membership_formset': formset})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add MemberShip</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a new MemberShip</h1>
    <form id="form-container" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{membership_formset.management_form}}
        {% for form in membership_formset %}
            <div class="membership-form">
                {{form.as_p}}
                <hr>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button id="add-form" type="button">Add Another MemberShip</button>
        <button type="submit">Create MemberShips</button>        
    </form>
    </body>

    <script>
        let membershipForm = document.querySelectorAll(".membership-form")
        let container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
        let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
        let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")

        let formNum = membershipForm.length-1
        addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

        function addForm(e){
            e.preventDefault()

            let newForm = membershipForm[0].cloneNode(true)
            let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g')

            formNum++
            newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)
            container.insertBefore(newForm, addButton)
            
            totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`)
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier on your users NOT to ask for the number of memberships first.  Instead, just have a single page where they enter a membership, with an "Add Another" button, and a "Finish" or "Go" button.  THEN you can count up how many they provided.

Comment: Thanks, Dear for replying to me. I want to add a number from a user that he will enter numbers then will add forms equal to the numbers. 

With click add more button I'm adding already which is working but want to custom with user enter number. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I'm telling you that is NOT the user-friendly way to do this.  What if he accidentally enters 3 but really wanted 4 names?  What if they want to add a name later?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the (valid) UX concerns raised by other members, you can achieve the workflow you requested by using two pages and adding a param to the url for the second page. For example:

```
path("new-membership/", . . .),
path("new-membership/<int:num_members>/", . . .),
```

Then your new-membership page can simply use the form to redirect to the second-stage page with the proper number of memberships in the url. You don't even really need to use a form on the first page since you are not altering the database in any way.

Comment: Yes Dear @user2601064 how can I loop numbers in for the form in the template in the next page